# Edit a portion of video (using AVFoundation)

Tags: swift, video, avmutablecomposition, cmtime

I have some code, provided below. This will take 2 videos assets, and insert the 2nd asset into the first asset. As of right now I am calling a new `AVMutableComposition` every time and returning a whole new composition, which is time consuming. I would imagine there is a way to remove a section of video, insert another section, without having to make an entire composition. Any suggestions? (Code works, Really looking for time consumption decrease).

1) Is there a way to just change a portion of the video instead of (This is what I am doing currently every time I need to change a video)

- 1) making a NEW AVMutableComposition
- 2) Adding the first video
- 3) Adding second video
- 4) Adding last portion of first video

Or is there a way to ... (What I would like to do instead)

- 1) Obtain first video
- 2) Go to set time that I want changed (say at 10 seconds)
- 3) Remove amount of time I want out, then insert time of second video
- 4) There would be no step 4 as I would only be changing a portion of video, and not recreating an entire new one.

My current code

```
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    do {
        try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 600)), ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch _ {
        print("Failed to load first track")
    }

    let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    do {
        try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration), ofTrack: secondAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 600))

    } catch _ {
        print("Failed to load second track")
    }

    let thirdTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    do {
        try thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration+CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 600)), ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 600))

    } catch _ {
        print("Failed to load second track")
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I did on another question I asked

Comment: @Crashalot give me half hour to get back to you on that link or check out my profile and scavenge around

Comment: was this the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797626/144088

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Been busy

Comment: no problem, but you're saying this code sped up the export process substantially? it seems like it would still require a lot of time?

Comment: You have to create a new composition every time. It definitely takes my system time, depending on the size of the combined assets. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: a faster way to add an overlay to a video created by the device camera. so far, the best approach is to use avassetwriter and add the overlay while the video is made the first time, but the problem is how to convert the overlay (UIImage) into a CMSampleBuffer for the avassetwriter to use. any ideas?